# How to change model structure of Mobilnet-SSD in Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am doing to train a [Mobilnet-SSD](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config) for detect small heads.
So I want to add some box_predictor_layer in the front of the layer of network, like add a box_predictor_layer to connect 5/6th Convolution layer.

How to do it?
I read all .proto files, find [ssd.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/ssd.proto), and [ssd_anchor_generator.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/ssd_anchor_generator.proto), [box_predictor.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/box_predictor.proto).
But I don't know how to change them, because graph of tensorboard is so disorderly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add another "exit point" (i.e. feature map to apply detection on) from the backbone. Do so by adding the name of the layer in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_feature_extractor.py#L105), and `-1` in the corresponding place in `layer_depth` (this means you don't need to tell it what is the depth of the feature map, since it's given by the backbone).
If you only need to detect small heads, so you don't need to detect large ones, you can probably get rid of (at least some of) the additional SSD feature maps which are added after the backbone by the ''s in `from_layer` and 512, 256, 256, 128 in `layer_depth`.
Don't forget to modify `num_layers` in the config file accordingly:

```
model {
  ssd {
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: <num_of_feature_maps>
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I have another question. the output of this net are 4 nodes: detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections. But now I only need one node, how to merge these to a node? I think that only need to change [export_inference_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was having a similar problem as in the OP. However, I tried to follow the procedure you described and it doesn't work. I added a _Conv2d_5_pointwise_ in ssd_mobilenet_v1_feature_extractor.py (and the corresponding -1 field in layer_depth), and changed num_layers into the config file to 7 too, but I still get an error message stating that "ValueError: Number of feature maps is expected to equal the length of "num_anchors_per_location". Should I modify anything else?